# How to access Foreign key models with custom primary key in django

Tags: django, django-models

These are my two models:

In models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):

    person_no = models.IntegerField(max_length=10, primary_key='True')
    phone = models.IntegerField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'person'

class person_ext(models.Model):

    person_no = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    value = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'personExt'
```

I went to manage.py shell to test my model and I tried to access the cell_phone of a person given the person's id this way:

```
        p = Person.objects.get(pk=1)
        cell_phone = Person_ext.objects.get(person_no=p).filter(key='cell').value
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

`DatabaseError: (1054, "Unknown column 'personExt.person_no_id' in 'field list'")`

My database column is just "person_id" but django is looking for "person_no_id". What do I have to do to access the personExt data using a person_no from person.

Answer (score 5):

person_no_id is what I would expect for Django to look at. It appears that your database is actually out of sync with what your models expect. I would consider comparing the output of (sql)

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `personExt `;
```

and

```
python manage.py sql APPNAME
```

for the table in question. You can fix this problem by using migration tools like south, recreating the database, or manually editing the database to fix the field. Alternatively you can change the model if you're importing:

```
person_no = models.ForeignKey(Person, db_column="person_id")
```

Edit: primary_key should be True, not the string "True," Indentation looks wrong for the Meta class and you should consider naming person_ext as PersonExt instead.

Comment: I'm using two databases. I can't sync this model to the db because I can't write to it. My db table `personExt` has the column `person_no` which is the foreign key to `person` and `id` which is the primary key.

Comment: Based off what you said you should try my last suggest, change the django model to say db_column="person_no"

Comment: Fixed the indentation, changed `primary_key=True` and tried `p = Person.objects.get(pk=1)
        cell_phone = Person_ext.objects.get(person_no=p).filter(key='cell').value` but still no luck. I'm getting `DoesNotExist: person_ext matching query does not exist.`